# Building PySide 1.2.0: no pyside-uic

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, pyside

I compiled PySide 1.2.0 for python 3.3 on my machine (Ubuntu 13.04 x64), but, for some reason, pyside-tools don't get "compiled".

When I try to execute pyside-uic (after install) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyside-uic", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PySide==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'pyside-uic')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2382, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/PySide-1.2.0-py3.3.egg/PySide/scripts/uic.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pysideuic.driver import Driver
ImportError: No module named 'pysideuic'
```

The egg file doesn't have the pysideuic folder. And when I check the pyside_install/py3.3-qt4.8.4-64bit-release/lib folder, I found that a "python2.7" folder exist!!

I build the sources using the instructions from this page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide.

Please, help.

Comment: Please can you put the console output of build process somewhere ? thanks

Comment: Hi. This is the console output: pastebin.com/BKKpczAn

Comment: thanks, this looks like a bug in cmake build script. i will inform you when it's fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fixed now. Please get latest version of pyside-setup from github [1] and rebuild pyside distribution. Let me know if you have any issues.

[1] https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup

Comment: Hi. Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem. The output log: http://pastebin.com/pbnmR8kD.

One weird thing: The CMakeList.txt "reverts" to its old version after being cloned, failing to make the module.

I delete all the previous folders, I try it 3 times (just to be sure I don't used a wrong url) and nothing. The file just change before the compile process.

Comment: I try changing the file (CMakeList.txt) before the compilation of pyside-tools, and it works!

Now the problem is to know why the file change before the compile process.

Comment: Please can you send me the command line (not the output) with parameters you have used ? it look like you are using --version=1.2.0 parameter. Because You need to build development version (not release) you should omit the --version parameter. Regards

Comment: Indeed, I'm using the --version parameter.
python3 setup.py bdist_egg --version=1.2.0 --jobs=8 --no-examples.

Why is that a problem?

Comment: when using the --version paraneter, the setup script will checkout pyside modules for version specified by that parameter. For --version=1.2.0, the script will checkout pyside=1.2.0, shiboken=1.2.0 and pyside-tools=0.2.14. The fix was introduced in pyside-tools master branche, so you need to specify --version=1.3.0dev, or you entirely disable --version parameter. You can also list all version with --list-versions parameter and use the most recent version from list (it should be 1.3.0dev). To build latest dev version use: python3 setup.py bdist_egg --version=1.3.0dev --jobs=8 --no-examples

Comment: I figured out that already, after checking the setup script.
Well, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the pyside-uic.exe or uic.exe in python folder/scripts and copy it in the required directory. or if not found any script in the particular directory, then reinstall PySide and check for any logs that say where pyside UIC is installed. Because I have also used python 2.x and I have personally experienced this problem. Check out for the scripts subfolder in python installation directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).